# Background image to canvas using onDraw?

Tags: android

I am attempting to replace a standard black background with a custom image, but am unsure as to how I might implement it...

Code (the onDraw method):

```
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        //c.drawARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);

        if ( overlay.tick() )
            if ( !todraw.tick() )
                mintercept.endGame();
        todraw.draw(c, Layer.BACKGROUND);
        todraw.draw(c, Layer.CITIES);
        todraw.draw(c, Layer.TRAILS);
        todraw.draw(c, Layer.EXPLOSIONS);
        todraw.draw(c, Layer.MISSILES);
        todraw.draw(c, Layer.CHROME);
        overlay.draw(c, Layer.CHROME);
    }

    public abstract void reset();
}
```

The commented line was responsible for the black background (or so I believe...); the blank space is reserved for my implementation of a custom background image. How might I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Canvas has a [`drawBitmap`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20int,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) method: fetch your image using a `BitmapFactory` from a resource and draw it and you should be good to go.

Comment: Seems to work, but the not all of the image is showing (as if it's too big; but really, it's identical in size to the screen...). It also seems to slow performance in the emulator... will that translate over to physical devices?

Thanks for the tip, by the way.

Comment: Should be reasonably efficient: the emulator is pretty slow. It should render at pretty much the exact size: maybe border/margin/padding issues on the screen?